# Observing the complex sine function

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi guys I am trying to show that

Show that the function $f(z) = \sin(z)$ maps the $y$-axis one-to-one to the imaginary axis.

My thinking is simple if I observe $f(0)$ I know, I get $f(0)=0$ which shows the kernel is empty. Thus this is injective function. My question is it obvious that $\sin(z)$ is well defined?

Comment: The *kernel*? Is that really how you prove that a function is bijective? Look, $|z|=0$ iff $z=0$, is the function $z\to|z|$ bijective? You are asking if $\sin$ is well defined, but **how** do you define it on $\Bbb C$, exactly? It's rather standard to use either a series definition (with radius $\infty$) or the exponential as does mixedmath below. Is it well defined according to your standards? Or maybe you had in mind $\arcsin$, but here it's really $\sin z$, not $\arcsin z$. The function $z\to\sin z$ is **entire**. Also, what's the difference between the $y$ axis and the imaginary axis?

Comment: Note I am trying to show injective not bijective. It is standard trick in linear algebra to prove that a map is injective by showing that its ker contains no no zero vectors.

Comment: Yes. And this is not **linear** algebra.

Comment: Sorry for that, I was just asking trying to understand if the argument works and if not why.

Comment: No worry. Keep in mind that results proved in linear algebra course (almost?) always rely heavily on linearity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to proceed is to note that
$$ \sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$
So 
$$\sin(iy) = \frac{e^{-y} - e^y}{2i}.$$
The function $f(y) = e^{-y} - e^y$ takes $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
The derivative 
$$f'(y) = -ye^{-y} - e^y = -ye^{-y}(1 - e^{2y})$$
is always negative, and so $f(y)$ is injective. As $\lim_{y \to \pm \infty} f(y) = \mp \infty$, we see that $f$ is surjective.

Thus $\sin(iy) = -\frac{i}{2} f(y)$ takes every value on the imaginary axis exactly once.

I do not know how to respond to you asking about the definition of $\sin(z)$. So I will use the exponential definition given above, or equivalently its series definition.

Comment: To shorten the proof, you may also write that $\sin iz=i\sinh z$, and the restriction of $\sinh$ to $\Bbb R$ is a bijection.